# Why can't I find SaveToLayerFile output?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3

I have a feature class that has data for the whole month of January with 'date' as one of the attribute categories (labeled ARGH here). I want to grab the information for each day in January and stick it in it's own feature class, so I have 31 separate files. So, as you'll see in the code below, I perform a query for each day, make a feature layer for that day's info and save the layer file to my gdb.

I don't get any error messages when I run it. HOWEVER, I can't find the saved layer files anywhere. I've looked all over. I can't figure out where I've gone wrong.

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.workspace = "L:\\gathr\\indonesia\\Sara\\SAISData\\AAAS\\SAIS2.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

Source_File = "AIS_Jan2016_CorrectTIme"

field = "ARGH"
Day_List = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Source_File,"ARGH")]
Day_List1 = [x.encode('UTF8') for x in Day_List]
UniqueDay = set(Day_List1)
UniqueDay_List = list(UniqueDay)
print UniqueDay_List

arcpy.env.workspace = "L:\\gathr\\indonesia\\Sara\\SAISData\\AAAS\\SAIS2.gdb"
outputpath = "L:\\gathr\\indonesia\\Sara\\SAISData\\AAAS\\SAIS2.gdb"
for day_query in UniqueDay_List:
    out_layer = str(day_query)+ "lyr"
    out_layer_name= "s" + out_layer 
    #out_layer_fc= "fc" + out_layer

    #MakeFeatureLayer variables
    in_features = "AIS_Jan2016_CorrectTIme"

    where_clause = ['ARGH = ' + "'" + day_query + "'"]
    #so as an sql-type query this would be ARGH = 'day_query' or something similar
    print where_clause
    workspace = "L:\\gathr\\indonesia\\Sara\\SAISData\\AAAS\\SAIS2.gdb"

    try:
        #Execute MakeFeatureLayer
        print in_features
        print out_layer
        print where_clause
        print workspace
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features, out_layer, where_clause, workspace)

        #Execute SaveToLayerFile
        arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(in_layer, out_layer_name)

    except:
        print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

Answer (score 5):

A Layer file `.lyr` is a *file*, not something you can store in a geodatabase.  You are trying to store your new file inside `L:\gathr\indonesia\Sara\SAISData\AAAS\SAIS2.gdb` (your `arcpy.env.workspace`).

In order to save your layer file you will need to specify an output folder to save it in as part of your `out_layer_name`

```
out_layer_name = os.path.join(r"c:\myfolder", "s" + out_layer)
```

which will save your layer file to something like `c:\myfolder\sMyValuelyr` (where `MyValue` is the value from `str(day_query)` in the line `out_layer = str(day_query)+ "lyr"`)